# excel-vba - can't sum dictionary items in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I create a dictionary with some items and I need to sum the various items for every key.

But I can't. I post the code with some comments. Let me know if I have to add more deta

```
Sub dict_sum()

Dim dict as New Dictionary
Dim i As Integer
Dim pk As Variant
dim attr as variant
Dim attr_tmp As Variant

For i = start_range To end_range 'loop on the column range
    pk = ObjO.Cells(i, ObjO.Range("primary_key").Column)  'set the primary key for the dictionary 
    ReDim attr_tmp(1 To 4)  'read for the primary key cell the following for columns that contains numbers 
                            'and obviously are on the same row of the primary key  
        attr_tmp(1) = ObjO.Cells(i, ObjO.Range("xx1").Column)
        attr_tmp(2) = ObjO.Cells(i, ObjO.Range("xx2").Column)
        attr_tmp(3) = ObjO.Cells(i, ObjO.Range("xx3").Column)
        attr_tmp(4) = ObjO.Cells(i, ObjO.Range("xx4").Column)

            ReDim attr(1 To 1)
                'with the following passage i'm trying to pass the sum of the previously columns to one variable
                'that will be the item of the dictionary dict.
                attr(1) = attr_tmp(1) + attr_tmp(2) + attr_tmp(3) + attr_tmp(4)
            'now if the key pk doesn't exists in the dictionary, it add the key(pk) and the item(attr(1)) to thedictionary 
            'with the else condition.
            'If the key already exists, then add attr(1)to the key pk
            'THE PROBLEMS IS IN THIS PASSAGE >> THE SUM DICT(PK)+ATTR(1) DOESN'T WORK AND EVERY TIME IT PASS ME THE VALUE OF ATTR(1)    
            If dict.Exists(pk) Then
                dict(pk)(1) = dict(pk)(1) + attr(1)
            Else: dict.Add pk, attr
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Just wondering.. you realize`Range("xx1").Column` will return `.Cells(1,648).Column`. So, column 648.

Comment: yes, I've inserted a fake name for make the explanation simpler.If I type dict(pk)(1) + attr(1) on the Immediate window I receive the correct value. I don't understand why it can't pass the correct value to dict(pk)(1)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub dict_sum()

    Dim ObjO As Worksheet

    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim i As Integer, start_range As Integer, end_range As Integer
    Dim pkC As Integer, xx1C As Integer, xx2C As Integer, xx3C As Integer, xx4C As Integer
    Dim attrSum As Double

    set ObjO = Workbooks("MyWorkbookName") '<--| adjust it to your needs
    start_range = 1 '<--| adjust it to your needs
    end_range = 100 '<--| adjust it to your needs

    With ObjO
        pkC = .Range("primary_key").Column
        xx1C = .Range("xx1").Column
        xx2C = .Range("xx2").Column
        xx3C = .Range("xx3").Column
        xx4C = .Range("xx4").Column
        For i = start_range To end_range 'loop on the column range
            attrSum = .Cells(i, xx1C) + .Cells(i, xx2C) + .Cells(i, xx3C) + .Cells(i, xx4C)
            dict.Item(.Cells(i, pkC)) = dict(.Cells(i, pkC)) + attrSum
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: op: it's noteworthy that changing a value at `dictionary(Key)` automatically adds the key, if it doesnt exist. so, no need to `If Then Else`.

Comment: @NG83, did you get through it?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your help first. I'm still working on it. I can't fit this solution with my problem and I'm thinking of using a class first and then a dictionary on the class